# Octave with gnuplot: How to minimize space between legend marker and legend text

Tags: plot, gnuplot, octave, legend

I'm using octave 4.0.3 together with `graphics_toolkit("gnuplot")`. Is it possible to make the space between the legend marker and legend text smaller? 
It looks nice in the gnuplot window, but after printing it as .pdf or .png it looks like in the image below. This happens regardless of what `PaperSize` I set for the figure or what `FontSize` i use for the legend.

[image]

This is how i set my legend:

```
legend('Insert 1 ', 'Insert 2 ', 'Insert 3 ', 'location','southeast')
legend_props = findobj(gcf(),"type","axes","Tag","legend");
set(legend_props, "FontSize", 7);
```

(I'm using gnuplot as octave struggles with my specified legend position if i change the PaperSize.)

**EDIT**: I tried in on a different machine, which is running octave 4.2.1. There it produces a much nicer result with a smaller space. So it may be a bug with Octave 4.0.3. If possible i would still prefer a solution for 4.0.3 as I would need to compile 4.2.1 from source on my current OS (Ubuntu 16.10, sadly no package available).

**EDIT 2**: It is most likely a bug within 4.0.3, as it depends on the chosen font. The problem occurs in 4.0.3 with the font `CMU Serif` but not with the standard font.